# Cannot access an Object Reference instantiated by a sibling class

Tags: java, inheritance, nullpointerexception, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that declares a number of object references, specifically a JLabel.  I have two classes that both extend that class.  One of the children instantiates the JLabel and calls a couple of its methods.  That classes sibling attempts to call the setText method on the JLabel and I get a NullPointerException(The sibling that instantiates it is called before the other.)

I had thought that all children refer to the same object in memory and would thus modify the same object but apparently I'm wrong.  How can I get around this?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
public class BlahDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BlahChildOne blah = new BlahChildOne();
        BlahChildTwo blah2 = new BlahChildTwo();
    }
}
public abstract class Blah 
{
    protected JLabel label;
}
public class BlahChildOne extends Blah
{
    public BlahChildOne()
    {
        label = new JLabel();
    }
}
public class BlahChildTwo extends Blah
{
    public BlahChildTwo()
    {
        label.setText("Fred");
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException at BlahChildTwo when attempting to setText.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to show any code since it is a conceptual question but i suppose i could write some up

Comment: Code IS necessary because the use of `new` dictates how objects are created on the heap. How you do what you say you do makes a big difference.

Comment: `BlahChildTwo` calls the constructor of Blah which never instantiates the JLabel. That means that `label` is null when you say `label.setText()`. "_I had thought that all children refer to the same object in memory_" is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, blah defines an instance field called `label` but does not initialise it

```
public abstract class Blah 
{
    protected JLabel label;
}
```

`BlahChildOne` initialises the `label` from `Blah`

```
public class BlahChildOne extends Blah
{
    public BlahChildOne()
    {
        label = new JLabel();
    }
}
```

`BlahChildTwo` does not initialises the `label` from `Blah`, so it is still `null`...

```
public class BlahChildTwo extends Blah
{
    public BlahChildTwo()
    {
        label.setText("Fred");
    }
}
```

Neither `BlahChildOne` or `BlahChildTwo` share information between them (they have commonality through inheritance from `Blah`, but the actually information is each owns).

Think of it like identical twins, they might share commonality, but just because one get's sick, doesn't mean the other will, they are their own self contained instance.

IF you want to share information between classes, you should consider providing a reference to the class with the information you want to share, for example...

```
public class BlahChildTwo extends Blah
{
    public BlahChildTwo(Blah blah)
    {
        label = blah.label;
        label.setText("Fred");
    }
}
```

But I'd really like to see a use case for something so drastic...

### Why `static` is consider **bad**

Lets assume...

```
public abstract class Blah 
{
    protected static JLabel label;
}
```

Now in your code, you do something like...

```
BlahChildOne bco = new BlahChildOne();
add(bco.label); // It the label to the screen...
BlahChildTwo bct = new BlahChildTwo();
```

Okay, so far, so good.  Now imagine, somewhere else in your code, you do...

```
BlahChildOne bco = new BlahChildOne();
BlahChildTwo bct = new BlahChildTwo();
```

...But why hasn't the screen updated?  Because `Blah#label` is no longer pointing to the `JLabel` which you previously added to the screen, you've lost that reference.

This is pain in the debugger to find, even when you know what you are looking for, because there is no accountability, any class that extends `Blah` can create a new instance of `JLabel` and assign it to `label`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and all the info.  What if after creating new bco and bct objects the second time you did "add(bco.label);" again, would it work?  Not that that is the best way to do things, but it would work?

Comment: @Khaines0625 Only if you knew to remove the previous instance first. The problem here, again, is accountability, you can't control who might (accidentally or otherwise) change the reference to `label`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - powerful point. Makes sense. I shouldn't have just blindly suggested 'static', huh? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Friend, you must be new to [object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

A class is a template for objects. When you instantiate a class (i.e. `new Child()`), memory is allocated on the heap to store that object's instance variables. That memory, containing the object's variables, is for that one object alone. Each time you create an object, it has its own instance variables in a separate memory space.

Comment: Well, I've learned than multiple object references can point to the same space in memory but am pretty new to inheritance so I wasn't sure how it all worked.  I'm only in my second semester of classes.

Answer (score 0):

This line  `protected JLabel label;` doesn't creates Object , It is only reference variable , So when both class extends Abstract class . Both Class have their own seperate copies of Reference Variable

**BlahChildTwo** has his own copy of JLabel reference variable which is not instantiated that is why you are facing `NullPointerException`

Now coming to your question

`I had thought that all children refer to the same object in memory and would` `thus modify the same object but apparently I'm wrong. How can I get` `around this?`

Yes all children will refer to same object if that is an **object** Not **Reference Variable**

Answer (score -1):

All children do *not* refer to the same object. Each child object will be a new object that will have its own copy of all references declared in the parent as well as a copy of all references declared in itself.

If you want to access the same reference between classes, try making it `static` in the parent class.

Comment: @Khaines0625 Considering how you don't know what the `static` keyword actually does, beware of side effects.

Comment: No, don't use static!  Clearly both child classes extend from `Blah`, `label` will be `null` unless it's initialised...

Comment: True, @MadProgrammer. He needs to make sure the function that initializes the static reference is called first always.

Comment: By making it static it means that that JLabel Object is, in a way, shared amongst all of the children classes, right?  Any change I make to the JLabel will be seen amongst all children? That's what I need.

Comment: This is a personal nit pick: `static` is dangerous, especially in a UI based environment (I'd guess it can create just as much mess anywhere).  IF the information REALLY needs to be shared, pass a reference of the first class to the second class, you could then obtain a reference to the label and make the modifications you need there...but that makes me wonder why the second class needs to extend from `Blah`, but that might be implementation details which are not been shared

Comment: @Khaines0625 `static` is a poor design choice and you seriously need to spend time thinking about your design if this becomes a choice.  It's simply WAY to easy to end up with erroneous references to things and not know what you are physically modifying, because some other piece of code changed the base reference without your knowledge.  For example, add `BlahChildOne moreBlah = new BlahChildOne();` after `blah2`, now what is everyone referencing?  The original reference has been lost...

Comment: Okay.  I usually do avoid static because the times I've tried Its caused weird problems and i frankly don't understand the details of what it does.  It would take a while to describe my overall design plan so I won't.  I'm just taking on a big programming project(a game) on the side of my school work to help me learn.  The whole experience is mostly for learning, so thanks for all the input.

Comment: @Khaines0625 Good learning experience, good opportunity to put into practise good habits.  I spend a lot of time on my personal projects thinking, "If I just cut this corner, it would be so much easier", but that forms bad habits, not just in coding, but also in thinking - IMHO

Comment: Don't use static blindly  , first go and understand  what are static variable , why use of static variables solves this , why using of static variables removes NullPointerException .