# My JLabel and GUI code in a paintcomponent method do not draw at the same time

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent

When I try to draw a JLabel or my GUI, whatever I add to my JFrame last is drawn and the rest is just never drawn or painted over. I would appreciate if you could help me find a solution to draw the JLabel at a specific place along with my GUI. I have heard about layout and how it could help me with that, but there were many different people saying different things about this subject. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics.*;


public class Main extends JPanel
{
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    double w = screenSize.getWidth();
    double h = screenSize.getHeight();
    static JFrame f = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    static JPanel p = new JPanel();
    int width = (int)w;
    int height = (int)h;
    int width1a = width/2 - 300;
    int width2a = width/2 - 100;
    int width3a = width/2 + 100; 
    int width4a = width/2 + 300;
    int height1from = (int)height - 100;
    int height1to = (int)height - (int)(height/1.05);
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello World !");
        f.add(l);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawLine(width1a, height1from, width1a, height1to);
        g2.drawLine(width2a, height1from, width2a, height1to);
        g2.drawLine(width3a, height1from, width3a, height1to);
        g2.drawLine(width4a, height1from, width4a, height1to);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        f.setSize(400,300);
        f.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);      
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello World !");               
        f.add(p);
        f.add(m);
    }
}
```

Please tell me if I was unclear or anything. I just want the JLabel and the GUI drawings to appear on the JFrame. Feel free to suggest anything I should redo and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, ever, add components to a component from within a paint method. You should never modify the state of a component in any way from within a paint method, painting is for painting, nothing else.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing...

You are adding three components to the same position within a `BorderLayout`, generally, only the last component would normally be shown, as it's the one that is been managed by the `BorderLayout`

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details.

You should also make sure that you are creating your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Painting is also contextual to the component been painted, that is, the `0x0` is the top left corner of the component, any painting done beyond the visual range of the component is simply lost.

You should also avoid the use of `static`, generally, this is a good indication that you have a problem with your design, it gets especially messy within a UI.  If you really want to hear me whinge about the evils of `static`, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291791/cannot-access-an-object-reference-instantiated-by-a-sibling-class/28292117#28292117)

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel blue = new JPanel();
                blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JLabel("Hello world"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.add(blue, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Hello World"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            // This could actually be achieved using a EmptyBorder and a LineBorder
            // but this demonstrates the point...
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the try and catch statement necessary to just draw and add a JLabel?

Comment: I have a personal, deep seated, hatred of the default look and feel.  I prefer the system look and feel, this is my personal preference, if you don't want to set the look and feel, you don't have to you

Comment: Also, how could you specify a location for the JLabel if the TestPane's layout was BorderLayout? Would you use a container to do so?

Comment: It would depend.  A different layout manager might give you better control